# How other app can use same database in android .if databse is encrypted?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I have one question.

I have two app in my android sdk.

1 - first app with encrypted DB in SDCARD.

2- second app no database.

```
is it possible second app can access the encrypted DB .
```

if yes please **assist** me .

Comment: yes. but it would either need a contentprovider or the read write on the file and the key/password to the db. (contentprovider is cleaner, see stefan answer)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this will be through ContentProviders. 
This allows your app A, to provide some public methods to request/alter data from it's own Database by other Apps as long as they know the URI (you can see it as a little key/secret).

One of the best guides on this you can probably find [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Comment: with content provider i can use password.